# AWS S3 static website when refreshed, goes to the main page

Tags: amazon-s3, static, web-hosting

I hosted my website (made by VueJS changed to dist file) on AWS S3.
It has several pages (it is not one-page site)

- `{mydomain}`
- `{mydomain}/about`
- `{mydomain}/contact`

At first, I had Error 404: NoSuchKey when refreshing.

I read other stackoverflow questions, and put *index.html* on the custom error file.
Now there is no error comming out, but goes to the main page `{mydomian}` when refreshing.

Going from `{mydomian}` to `{mydomain}/about` by clicking works fine.

However, I refresh on the page on `{mydomain}/about`, it goes to `{mydomain}`.
(I want it to reload the `{mydomain}/about` page.)

The files (from dist) I put in the S3 for hosting is [here](https://github.com/HITTHEANTS/test).

The original code (not the dist file, but the source code) is [here](https://github.com/HITTHEANTS/hit-the-ants-site).

Comment: Hi I am also having similar problem, did you find the solution? Please share if you have.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this and replace it with your domain name in AWS s3 ->your bucket ->static web hosting-> edit ->Redirection rules section

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
<Condition>
<HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
</Condition>
<Redirect>
<HostName>example.com</HostName>
<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#!/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
</Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Use the below link for reference
[Redirect-all-routes-to-index-html-when-hosting-a-react-angular-webapp-on-s3/](https://harishkm.in/2020/07/30/redirect-all-routes-to-index-html-when-hosting-a-react-angular-webapp-on-s3/)